# Python advanced list ordering

Tags: python, list, sorting

The following list has format (ID, level, value):

```
[(A, 1, None),
 (B, 1, None),
 (C, 1, None),
 (A, 2, 1.1),
 (B, 2, 5.0),
 (C, 2, 5.0),
 (C, 3, 40),
 (B, 3, 55)]
```

So the catch is to sort items of the same *level* with the same *value* according to their values from one *level* lower. If values one *level* below are equal, it goes 2 levels below, and so on. So the end list should look like this:

```
[(A, 1, None),
 (C, 1, None), <- this moved up because @ lvl3 C['value'] < B['value']
 (B, 1, None),
 (A, 2, 1.1),
 (C, 2, 5.0), <- this moved up because @ lvl3 C['value'] < B['value']
 (B, 2, 5.0),
 (C, 3, 40),
 (B, 3, 55),]
```

Could somebody suggest an algorithm to achieve that? Btw, I always get the starting list sorted by *value* and then by *level*

Comment: write your custom comparison method for some_list.sort(your_method)

Comment: I've updated my question. A is at the top because at level 2 A['level'] < B['level']

Comment: @user2799617: writing a custom method was reasonably challenging, actually.

Comment: Voted to reopen; questions asked in comments have been answered and the post was edited to clarify how the sort is supposed to work. It was certainly clear enough to me to produce a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a lookup table to determine the values per `(ID, level)` tuple. You'll need to add all possible level lookups to the sort key:

```
# Lookup for values by (id, level)
values = {}
minlevel, maxlevel = float('inf'), float('-inf')
for id_, level, value in inputlist:
    values[id_, level] = value
    if level < minlevel:
        minlevel = level
    if level > maxlevel:
        maxlevel = level

def level_sort(tup):
    id_, level, value = tup
    sortkey = [level]
    for l in range(minlevel, maxlevel + 1):
        sortkey.append(values.get((id_, l)) if l >= level else None)
    return sortkey

sorted(inputlist, key=level_sort)
```

The sort function generates a list of values to sort on, starting with the value at their own level (filling in `None` for any lower levels) plus the values for the same ID at higher levels.

For example, for the `(B, 1, None)` and `(C, 1, None)` tuples, the sort function outputs:

```
>>> level_sort(('B', 1, None))
[1, None, 5.0, 55]
>>> level_sort(('C', 1, None))
[1, None, 5.0, 40]
```

where only the last value differs and determines the final sort order.

For this to work, you need to know the minimum and maximum levels in the input list first, hence the more elaborate map building loop.

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> A, B, C = 'ABC'
>>> inputlist = [(A, 1, None),
...  (B, 1, None),
...  (C, 1, None),
...  (A, 2, 1.1),
...  (B, 2, 5.0),
...  (C, 2, 5.0),
...  (C, 3, 40),
...  (B, 3, 55)]
>>> values = {}
>>> minlevel, maxlevel = float('inf'), float('-inf')
>>> for id_, level, value in inputlist:
...     values[id_, level] = value
...     if level < minlevel:
...         minlevel = level
...     if level > maxlevel:
...         maxlevel = level
... 
>>> def level_sort(tup):
...     id_, level, value = tup
...     sortkey = [level]
...     for l in range(minlevel, maxlevel + 1):
...         sortkey.append(values.get((id_, l)) if l >= level else None)
...     return sortkey
... 
>>> pprint(sorted(inputlist, key=level_sort))
[('A', 1, None),
 ('C', 1, None),
 ('B', 1, None),
 ('A', 2, 1.1),
 ('C', 2, 5.0),
 ('B', 2, 5.0),
 ('C', 3, 40),
 ('B', 3, 55)]
```